# UNIXコマンドおよびディレクトリ名の由来は？

Tags: linux, unix

ここ最近サーバーをいじることが多く、UnixコマンドおよびLinuxコマンドを使用する機会が増えています。ところで気になったのですが

`ls`, `rm`, `cd`, `mkdir`, `grep`, `dd`, `chmod`, `su` などのコマンド
`/var`, `/usr`, `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/tmp` などのディレクトリ名

これらの由来はいったいなんなんでしょうか？

ついさっきまで
`dd` は `data dump` の略
`su` は `super user` の略
`/usr` は `user` の略だろうと思い込んでいました

しかし友人から
`dd` は `dataset definition` の略
`su` は `switch user` の略
`/usr` は `User Services and Routines` の略であると

知らされ、由来やなんという言葉が略されたのか知りたいと思いました

Answer (score 13):

まとめました Wiki として投稿します
追加・編集などはご自由にどうぞ

- **コマンド**

`ls` = `list`
`mv` = `move`
`cd` = `change directory`
`cp` = `copy`
`rm` = `remove`
`mkdir` = `make directory`
`rmdir` = `remove directory`
`chown` = `change owner`
`chmod` = `change mode`
`cat` = `catenate || concatenate`
`grep` = `"g/RE/p" || globally search a regular expression and print`
`ping` = `Packet InterNet Groper`
`sh` = `shell`
`bash` = `Bourne Again SHell`
`su` = `Super User` || `Switch User || Substitute User`
`sudo` = `superuser do`
`vi` = `visual`
`sed` = `Stream Editor`
`uniq` = `unique`
`awk` = `Aho, Weinberger, Kernighan` # 3人の作者の名前
`man` = `manual`
`pwd` = `print working directory`
`bg` = `background`
`fg` = `foreground`
`ps` = `process status`
`du` = `disk usage`
`df` = `disk free`
`dd` = `Dump Data / Data Definition`
`passwd` = `password`
`tar` = `Tape Archive`
`wall` = `Write to ALL users`
`xargs` = `eXecute ARGumentS` # 要出典
`uname` = `UNIX Name`

- **ディレクトリ**

`/bin` = `binary`
`/sbin` = `System Binary`
`/usr` = `User Services and Routines` # Userの略ではない
`/var` = `variable`
`/lib` = `library`
`/tmp` = `temporary`
`/dev` = `device`
`/etc` = `Et Cetra`
`/proc` = `process`
`/sys` = `system`
`/ucb` = `University of California at Berkeley`

- **その他**

`tty` = `TeleTYpe`
`stdin` = `Standard In`
`SQL` = `Structured English Query Language`
`rc` = `Run Command` # .bashrcなど

> ソース 
>   [Linuxコマンドは単語の意味を理解するとグッと身近なものになる](http://qiita.com/tetsuya/items/46888bb4dfc8a6bfef02)
>   [新版 UNIX 由来/読み方辞書](http://x68000.q-e-d.net/~68user/unix/unix-term-dic.html)
>   [UNIX用語 由来/読み方辞書 version 1.6 (Feb 13 1995)](http://x68000.q-e-d.net/~68user/unix/original-unix-term-dic.html)

Comment: su は substitute user の略のようです https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/su

Comment: grep の由来は英単語の略より ed(1) のコマンド "g/RE/p" の方がよく知られています。

Comment: 「grep の由来は英単語の略より ed(1) のコマンド "g/RE/p" の方がよく知られています」これすごい

Comment: ping は ping pong の ping とか、ソナーの ping とかだと思ってました。

Comment: /usr は元々 user (古代のUnixでは、/usr 以下にホームディレクトリがあった。) だったけど、後に "User Services and Routines" として再定義されたというのが正確なところじゃないかと。

Comment: dd は convert and copy で cc になるはずだけど、cc がコンパイラに使われていたので dd になったという経緯。昔の JUS (Japan Unix Society) 会誌に載っていたはず。

Comment: Structured Query Language は今のSQLとは異なる言語 (IBMが作った) のことで、SQL は特に何の略でも無いというのが公式のスタンスです。(まるでDVDみたいな)

Comment: dd (convert and copy)はIBM、EBCDIC、ASCIIの文字コードを変換をする高々[500 行程度のツール](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-3-Snapshot-Development/usr/src/cmd/dd.c)だった。

Comment: Wiki として投稿したので修正・追加・編集などはご自由にどうぞ。私一人の知識ではとてもカバーしきれないのでご協力ください。

Comment: suは初期のUnixではSuper Userになる為のコマンド(他のユーザへの変更機能はない)でマニュアルでもbecome ther super-userとなっているので元々はSuper Userの略だったと思われます。Unix Version 2のマニュアルではまだbecome privileged user(Descriptionではbecome the super-user)になっています。 Switch UserやSubstitute Userは他のユーザへの変更機能が付いた後の後付けの意味だと思います。
ftp://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/unix/UnixArchive/PDP-11/Distributions/research/1972_stuff/unix_2nd_edition_manual.pdf